# gpedit missing from Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows-10, gpedit

It seems that the `Group Policy Editor` (`gpedit`) is missing for `Windows 10 Home`. If you do WindowsKey+R and enter "gpedit.msc" you get the following message:

> Windows cannot find 'gpedit.msc'

What are the steps required to install `gpedit` on `Windows 10 Home`? Is there a `Microsoft` sanctioned download of `gpedit` from the `Microsoft` domain?

Comment: Agreed, it is a duplicate of that question. I am just surprised that this question does not show up when I search for "gpedit windows 10", because I did check for a question like this before I posted.